# How do I identify the lens mount used for an old Soligor lens?

Tags: lens-mount, old-lenses, soligor

Soligor wide-auto 1:2.8 f=28mm
[image]

Comment: Adapter to go onto what camera?

Comment: I've edited the question; I think it's actually one step earlier than asking for an adapter, but simply asking what mount it's made for. From that, you can figure out the right adapter for any other specific mount (if that combination is possible).

Answer (score 2):

This lens was made in many, many different versions over the years — Soligor primarily (or exclusively?) licensed other company's products and attached their name. [This forum post](http://forum.mflenses.com/soligor-12-8-f28mm-21and-versions-t30866.html) identifies at least 21 different versions, and those may come in multiple mounts.

I'm pretty sure that *this* one has an old Minolta bayonet mount (Minolta MC/MD). That's substantiated by the label **MIN**, which presumably indicates **Min**olta. You can compare many old lens mounts [on this page](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html) — or, a google images search can be very helpful too.

For adapting this to a modern DSLR, the bad news is that the flange focal distance is roughly the same as modern lens mounts. See [Is it possible to adapt lens from one brand into another brand's body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/is-it-possible-to-adapt-lens-from-one-brand-into-another-brands-body) for more on that. You *can* get adapters, but they need to contain glass in order to retain infinity focus, and therefore will either be very expensive or compromise image quality. If, instead, you want to adapt to a mirrorless camera system, you may have better luck — see for example [How can I use a manual-focus Minolta MC Rokkor-PF 55mm SLR lens on a four-thirds system?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57551/how-can-i-use-a-manual-focus-minolta-mc-rokkor-pf-55mm-slr-lens-on-a-four-thirds)

Comment: KEH has a [pretty extensive identification guide](http://www.kehblog.com/2011/12/lens-mount-guide-part-1.html), too.

Comment: Agree, the notch configuration and aperture ring coupler look like MC/MD

Comment: @Blrfl the link to KEH's blog is dead (they killed kehblog.com, migrated it to blog.keh.com). Here is the [updated link to the lens identification guide](http://blog.keh.com/2011/12/02/the-lens-mount-guide-part-1/).

Comment: The KEH link is *again* updated and is now three parts. part1: https://www.keh.com/blog/the-lens-mount-guide-part-1 part2: https://www.keh.com/blog/the-lens-mount-guide-part-2 part3: https://www.keh.com/blog/the-lens-mount-guide-part-3 Note it's less that usefull now that somehow the img tags were stripped (you need to click each one to see the image!)