# What is the mount on an old lens that says "For Canon" with patent number 3500735?

Tags: canon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, old-lenses, tamron

I'm trying to find the correct lens mount or adapter to use with my Canon T3i. The mount has patent number 3500735 and says "For Canon".

[image: mount]

Comment: For future reference, what make/model is the lens? (Eg.,what does it say on the other side?)

Comment: And if you have a more-clear photo, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The "For Canon" is a pretty big hint, narrowing things down significantly. Since it's clearly not the current "EOS" mount, the obvious guess is that it's the previous manual-focus Canon mount, called "FD".

Your image is kind of blurry, but a quick Google search or a look at a [guide like this one on Keh.com](http://www.kehblog.com/2011/12/lens-mount-guide-part-1.html) ([thanks @Blrfl](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60447/how-do-i-identify-the-lens-mount-used-for-an-old-soligor-lens/60448#comment104963_60448)) will confirm this — it's Canon FD.

You can find adapters fairly easily (like [this one](http://smile.amazon.com/Fotodiox-Mount-Adapter-Camera-Digital/dp/B003EB0AXY)), but note that because the flange focal distance of the older mount is *shorter*, the adapter needs to contain glass in order to retain focus at a distance, which means that (especially with a $40 adapter) image quality will be compromised. (So, basically, unless you're just doing it for fun, it's not necessarily *worth* it.)

Answer (score 1):

The mount pictured *is* for [Canon FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_FD_lens_mount). For comparison, see [What is the breech mount on this Hanimex lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104697/75526)
 Canon FD is *not* a good mount to adapt to EOS cameras with EF/EF-S mounts.

However, the patent number 3500735 and exposed gear on the side indicates that the mount shown is *not* on the lens itself, but on an adapter for a [Tamron](http://www.adaptall-2.com/history/Tamron_History.html) universal mount. I would need more pictures to see which adapter it is, but I would *guess* it is for the **Adaptall-2 bayonet mount**. If that is the case, you can **get an Adaptall-EF (Tamron-EOS) adapter to use the lens with your Canon camera**. To detach the existing adapter from the lens, you need to press a tab on the side to release it.

Mounts that *can* be adapted to EF/EF-S include:

- M42 and T2 screw mounts
- Nikon F/AI/etc mount
- Olympus OM mount
- Pentax PK mount
- Tamron Adaptall mount